# How to format multiple authors name, affiliation and email in a paper?

Tags: publications, email, authorship, affiliation

I am writing a paper with my teacher and his teacher. I don't know the standard of writing authors name, affiliation and email in the paper. I am using **IEEEtran** template for an IEEE conference. If the authors are in different department or university there is no problem we can use column author name like this:

```
     Author one                  Author two                 Author three
   Department one              Department two             Department three
   University one              University two             University three
author.one@uni-one.edu     author.two@uni-two.edu     author.three@uni-three.edu
```

but what if two of them be in a same department and just two of them has a .edu email address? In this situations we can use another style like this:

```
        Author one*!, Author two*! and Author three^#
              *Department One, University One
              ^Department two, University two
          !{Author.one, Author.two}@univ-one.edu
                #Author.three@univ-one.edu
```

or it should be like this?

```
        Author one*, Author two* and Author three^
             *Department One, University One
          {Author.one, Author.two}@univ-one.edu
             ^Department two, University two
                Author.three@univ-one.edu
```

My question is this: What is the right format in this case when different authors with different affiliation, department and email should be on a paper?

In my specific, we all are from the same Univ. and Department but they both have .edu email and I don't have one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your question how to format addresses using the IEEEtran template? If so, then this question probably belongs on the TeX Stack Exchange board instead of this one.

Comment: @aeismail That was what I had doubt for. but I know how to use tex to write any of those forms. I am looking for the format standard no matter it is latex or word template.

Comment: There is no universal format standard. As F'x suggests, you need to use the format prescribed by the organization you're submitting to (and an organization like IEEE should _definitely_ have one).

Comment: I would just do something easy to read and unambiguous. If there are some standards, you'll be informed of those by the editors at some point but, most likely, everything not offending the eye will pass.

Comment: I don't understand.  What's wrong with the first format?  So what if Department One and Department Two are identical?  Ink is cheap!

Comment: @JeffE You're right. It has no problem to list them like the first format. But it's the matter of writing less. And I wanted to hear some professional opinion on this too. I used the second format once and now I think it's a little complicated and confusing but interesting. Little confusion is good. The first format I much easier an clearer. simple is good either. I think it's the matter of personal opinion at the end. no global rule.

Answer (score 7):

We had a similar complicated case in our [paper](http://eswc-conferences.org/sites/default/files/papers2013/hees.pdf). I'd suggest this as a good way to do it.

For your own case, add a comma after the braces, followed by your email.

Here's how it would look like:

```
{Author.one, Author.two}@univ-one.edu, Author.three@univ-ten.edu
```

I am assuming your username tells the reader that it is yours (has your lastname, initials or so). Additionally, do your best to sort the emails such that they follow the same order of authors.

Answer (score 5):

Just look up previous conference proceedings and do the same!